# My search bars width will not go below 200px

Tags: html, css

As of right now I have managed to have the search bar change width at all resolutions, but once I get to smaller screen sizes and need the search bars width to go below 200px, it won't, meaning that my search bar goes below instead of inline.

**[1280x800](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFgId.jpg)** and set width of 300px

**[1024x768](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kfo0.jpg)** and set width of 150px (**DOESN'T WORK**)

For reference, the website is [Redec](https://www.redecindustrial.com/), and I'm trying to make sure the search bar fits in the navigation bar at most resolutions. Please feel free to inspect the page as I am unable to list the raw html. Below is the CSS related to the search bar.

You can also use [Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=https%3A//www.redecindustrial.com/&w=1280&h=800&a=1) to accurately replicate the problem by changing the resolution easily.

Thank you in advance!

```
/*NAVBAR SEARCHBAR*/
#product-search-0{
    min-width: 350px;
    padding-top:17px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

/*navbar searchbar at 1400px*/
@media (max-width: 1400px){
    #product-search-0{
        min-width: 400px;
        padding-top: 17px;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    /*navbar searchbar at 1320px*/
    @media (max-width: 1320px){
        #product-search-0{
            min-width: 350px;
            padding-top: 17px;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
    }

    /*navbar searchbar at 1255px*/
    @media (max-width: 1255px){
        #product-search-0{
            min-width: 300px;
            padding-top: 17px;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
    }

    /*navbar searchbar at 1200px*/
    @media (max-width: 1200px){
        #product-search-0{
            min-width: 250px;
        }
    }

    /*navbar searchbar at 1100px*/
    @media (max-width: 1100px){
        #product-search-0{
            min-width: 200px;
        }
    }

    /*navbar searchbar at 1085px*/
    @media (max-width: 1085px){
        #product-search-0{
            min-width: 150px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you asking about the searchbar in header?

Comment: Yes in the navigation bar at the top of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this on line no 1722 in your CSS

```
@media (max-width: 1085px)
#product-search-0 {
    width: 110px !important;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

and this will not break.

Comment: Welcome, I would be happy to help more, Please up vote the answer too.

Comment: I haven't got enough rep :(

Answer (score 2):

Use this CSS

```
.x-nav-wrap.desktop {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 225px);
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this is given upVote, this code is messing up the header.

Answer (score 0):

```
.x-nav-wrap.desktop {
display: block;
max-width: 150px;
float: left;}
```

use max-width, it wont allow the search bar to grow from above mentioned max width size.